# Android harmony pixels

Tags: android, pixel, density-independent-pixel

i will explain my problem with an image !

[image]

I draw a figure with my finger and at the same time coordinates is sent  to clients.As you understand i am working with hard coded pixels.Algorithm is simple take the pixel and send to client and fill the pixel on client.

If the drawer phone has higher resulation than clients, the problem shows itself(missing or half shapes).
If the drawer phone has less resulation than clients , there is empty spaces on the edges.

by the way, i am using signalr to communicate clients and servers.

Comment: Get the resolution of the server and client screen and apply a proportionnality rule to your coordinates on the client device

Comment: yes i can send servers resulation to clients but what is the logic of proportionality rule on android ?

Comment: You can actually scale your shapes to the good resolution and they will be display correctly on the screen